# JetPack Navigation component with more than one activity?

Tags: android, uinavigationcontroller, android-jetpack-navigation

Is it possible to use the navigation component with more than one activity?

Comment: You just need to build multiple navigation graph. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two activities and their fragments. You can easily create multiple navigation graph to navigate for each activity. And if you would like to navigate from an activity/fragment to another activity, you need to make a separate navigation graph for replacing startActivity. You can see the examples here ,

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate#add